# Where should I ask question about server hardware?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I plan to convert a revamped desktop into a small server for professional use and would check if the existing hardware will be enough for the intended use.
Having several candidate machines, I need to distinguish what is necessary (or recommended) from what is superfluous.

Should I rather ask my question on:

- **Hardware Recommendations** (https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)
  because my question has to do with hardware,

or on

- **Server Fault** (https://serverfault.com/)
  because my question has to to with a server (altough not directly linked to administration) and because the community for servers is possibly more active here?

I'm myself an IT professional, but altough I gained some experience with servers there're not my core business.

Comment: For personal use, [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) would've taken it. Considering you're turning a desktop into a server I'm not sure it's professional enough for Server Fault, but if you think it is, I'd definitely pick that over Hardware Recs.